# Shopify Use Subdirectory in Asset Folder

Tags: shopify, liquid

Instead of putting all files in a place in the asset folder, I want to use CSS files in CSS folder, JS files in js folder and images in images folder. Then Include them in the asset folder, so that I can maintain the files easily.

I know Shopify doesn't support any sub-directories within the asset folder. But is there any trick to do that?

Comment: There could be one suggestion. Instead of uploading js or css files to Shopify themes, you can host them under a global link (site) and include those file links in theme.liquid or anywhere in your theme.

Comment: Then I'll need to use another web host for uploading my css, js or image files. So I think it is not a proper way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a Shopify employee. This is currently not possible and the reason is due to a limitation of the CDN they use. See that post [here](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/subdirectories-under-assets-159090).

Regardless, it's not good practice to have source files in the assets folder. Look into [the Shopify Slate tool](https://shopify.github.io/slate/). It's a theme scaffold and command line interface that helps keep your project structure organized.

You can organize your assets (both CSS and JavaScript) as source files with directory structures in a manner similar to this:

```
styles/
  global/
  modules/
  settings
  tools/
  vendor/
```

The command line tool takes care of compiling all the source files into one CSS/JS file! As a consequence, you don't need to worry about including the respective files with `<link>` or `<script>` tags because it's all taken care of already!

Comment: This is currently not possible and the reason is due to a limitation of the CDN they use.   That's doesn't even make sense.  What's the difference between the files being in a subdirectory or in one main directory.

Comment: @FabricioG most likely they're using Amazon S3 for file storage. S3 has no concept of "real" subdirectories (https://serverfault.com/questions/435827/what-is-the-difference-between-buckets-and-folders-in-amazon-s3). The "CDN" explanation is probably just a convenient way of saying "our file storage is just white-labeling Amazon S3 which doesn't support subdirectories"

Answer (score 0):

### Unfortunately, this is not something currently supported by Shopify (As of 14/Sept/2017)

I tried making sub-folders both at the root of my dev theme and in the asset folder of my dev theme in a few different ways, including through Shopify's ThemeKit editor, but Shopify did not let me create the folder.

Attempting to create sub-folders in the normal theme editor in the store (by naming an asset `subfolder/filename`) generates the error message: `Theme files may not be stored in subfolders`

Shopify's normal theme editor groups files by types so that they appear close together, and apparently that's as much as Shopify is giving us right now.

Comment: No changes as per December 2021, this is still not supported.

Comment: No changes as per the March 2024, this is still not supported.