How can someone use a local folder other than the assets folder on shopify?
So I came across this page:
Image of folder structure on the first example store, node/modules and dev/js folders visible
This page has node/modules and a dev/js folder for js that is not directly visible within the assets folder. A minified version is only visible. I can't access those files from the theme, no matter how I try to download it, thus leaving me to believe this is done locally. (only logical way)
Somehow those people managed to indirectly change the way shopify does its theme structure > assets,templates,sections,snippets etc. and add a new folder in a way that is only visible on the frontend. The same case also happens on a premium shopify theme named "sahara" -> Image of folder structure of the theme from Sahara
Here's a link to that theme: https://themes.shopify.com/themes/sahara/styles/sahara/preview
I've already tried adding node modules via webpack and gulp, but couldn't replicate the folders showing in the frontend as they currently are showing. Any ideas how this could work in Shopify?

Shopify does not allow uploading source folders such as node_modules, src, or any recursive folder in assets to their CDN due to their filesystem restrictions. If you're trying to resolve map files, they are precompiled with a bundler like Webpack.
For more details, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47086008/673223

If you take a loook at the sources from the 2 screenshots provided, you will clearly see the directories as well in the frontend. So I am aware of Webpack and Gulp as mentioned but I can't get to seem to replicate the exact same working method used by the theme Sahara and the shop miacara.com
